# type object 'Adam' has no attribute 'compute_gradients'

Tags: keras, optimization, gradient, loss

I am going to calculate the loss gradient with respect to networks parameters (weights) while I am having multiple outputs. I implemented following command

```
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam.compute_gradients(loss)
```

it promted following error:

AttributeError: type object 'Adam' has no attribute 'compute_gradients'*

Q1 : does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

Q2 : I have got multiple outputs, is there any way to calculate each individual loss gradient w.r.t weights?

Comment: The optimizer does not compute gradients, if you check the documentation Adam does not have a compute_gradients function.

Comment: Assuming this is Tensorflow 1.x, this function actually does exist, although (IIRC) only in the "native" TF optimizers, not the Keras ones. However, OP is not actually instantiating an object; they are calling it like a class method, which doesn't work either way.

Comment: actually I want to get the gradient of loss w.r.t weights. I think this command is the right one 

tf.keras.optimizers.Adam.get_gradients

but it will need me to give it loss and parameters. I am not sure how to feed the parameters.